# Google Search Console: page with redirection

Tags: redirect, google-search-console

I have a Serious SEO problem width Google Search Console on my website:

Error: "Page with redirection" - "Those pages are not indexed or casted on Google" (self translated from french sorry).

Exemples:
site without www
site with www

I've made my htaccess according on what I found on the web:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?#?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?$ index.php?page=$1&data=$2&niv3=$3&niv4=$4 [L]
```

Note: I use the subdomain: admin.site.com to have an administrator panel.
I'd like to keep it

Also I've set the canonical tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="[url]" />
```

I don't know what to do to index the site properly.
Thank you very much for you help.

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?#?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?$ index.php?page=$1&data=$2&niv3=$3&niv4=$4 [L]
```

canonical tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="[url]" />
```

Comment: Are you talking about URLs without the www? If so, you correctly redirect them to www so you can ignore their status in the search console. You may need to modify your .htaccess if you want the admin subdomain to work.